# SVG html tag not reading vh units on Safari. Works fine in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, safari

Okay so Im working on an svg element to greet visitors to a webpage. I was all set to go, the svg imagespace rendered perfectly well on Chrome. Then I go to check it on Safari and find out that safari for some reason wasn't reading the vh/vw properties correctly. The code for the layout is as follows, please help I've tried almost everything. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <svg width="100vw" height="88vh" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">
      <text id="sidename" x="-44vh" y="48" text-anchor="middle" style="color:black; font-family:serif; font-size:44.5;" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-90)" >TITLE TEXTILE</text>
      <image class="sideicons" width="150" height="150" x="100vw" y="22vh" transform="translate(-180,-75)" href="https://cdn.glitch.global/03f12696-08e6-4dc6-a91d-f09423b082b8/123.svg?v=1664485571668"/>
      <image class="sideicons" width="150" height="150" x="100vw" y="44vh" transform="translate(-180,-75)" href="https://cdn.glitch.global/03f12696-08e6-4dc6-a91d-f09423b082b8/123.svg?v=1664485571668"/>
      <image class="sideicons" width="150" height="150" x="100vw" y="68vh" transform="translate(-180,-75)" href="https://cdn.glitch.global/03f12696-08e6-4dc6-a91d-f09423b082b8/123.svg?v=1664485571668"/>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><text x="25vw" y="26" text-anchor="middle" style="color:black; font-family:monospace; font-size:13.31;">LinkedIn</text></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><text x="50vw" y="26" text-anchor="middle" style="color:black; font-family:monospace; font-size:13.31;">Instagram</text></a>
      <a href="https://google.com"><text x="75vw" y="26" text-anchor="middle" style="color:black; font-family:monospace; font-size:13.31;">Google</text></a>
      <text x="50vw" y="48vh" text-anchor="middle" style="color:white; font-family:serif; font-size:60;" transform="translate(103,54)">Title</text>
      <text x="50vw" y="48vh" text-anchor="middle" style="color:black; font-family:serif; font-size:60;" transform="translate(-113,-58)">Title</text>
      <text x="50vw" y="48vh" text-anchor="middle" style="color:black; font-family:serif; font-size:60;" transform="translate(0,0)">Title</text>
    </svg>
    
    <p style="color:grey;">Copyrighted '22</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Chrome Render:[Chrome SVG Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcgO4.png)
Safari Render:[Safari SVG Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7EgE.png)

Comment: I guess you'll have to use some other units.

Comment: It works for a canvas element not an svg for some reason...